# Whats the main difference between a report chart and a dashboard?

Tags: reporting

What would be the main difference between a report chart and a Dashboard?
Report chart displays visual metrics too similar to dashboards, so I am trying to understand more about the two.

Thanks
Spidey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/reports_dashboards/reports_dashboards_overview

Well, a dashboard is much more than one chart for one report. It can display multiple components/visuals from many different reports (or just the same one) to give a large overview over a given area.

A report chart is just that, a visual chart for one given report's pulled records.

[image]